# Зачем в интерфейсе нужен виртуальный деструктор?

Tags: c++

Зачем в интерфейсе нужен виртуальный деструктор?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Начнём с того, что в *C++* нет интерфейсов. Но часто интерфейсом называют абстрактный класс, поэтому не будем особо придираться.

Для чего же в базовом классе нам нужен виртуальный деструктор? Рассмотрим следующие классы:

```
class A {
    public :
        ~A() { }
}

class B : public A {
    private :
        char* buffer;
    public :
        B() : buffer(new char[1024]) { }
        ~B() { delete[] buffer; }
}
```

А теперь сделаем следующее:

```
A* a = new B;
// ...
delete a;
```

В этом коде память, выделенная для `buffer` освобождена не будет! При удалении переменной `a` будет вызван метод `A::~A`, который не производит очистку памяти, выделенной в классе `B`. Чтобы избежать подобного рода ошибок, деструктор базового класса объявляют виртуальным. Тогда при разрушении экземпляра класса будет вызван "правильный" деструктор. А поскольку `virtual` наследуется, то достаточно объявить деструктор виртуальным только у базового класса, во всех дочерних он будет виртуальным автоматически. То есть, наш базовый класс `A` должен быть таким:

```
class A {
    public :
        virtual ~A() { }
}
```

---

Как верно заметил @alexolut в комментариях к соседнему ответу, всё ещё хуже. Согласно стандарту *C++* (5.3.5.3),

> if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor ***or the behavior is undefined***.

Перевод:

> Если статический тип удаляемого объекта отличается от его динамического типа, статический тип должен являться базовым классом динамического типа удаляемого объекта и статический тип должен иметь виртуальный деструктор, ***в противном случае поведение неопределено***.

Answer (score 5):

1. Потому что в Си++ нет интерфейсов.
2. Указатель на наследника может быть приведён к указателю на "интерфейс".
3. `delete` указателя вызовет деструктор того типа, с которым *объявлен* указатель.
4. Если этот деструктор виртуальный, то вызовется деструктор типа, созданного через `new`.
5. Если деструктор не виртуальный, то ты *потеряешь* очистку всего, что принадлежит наследнику, но не принадлежит предку. Точнее, формально, это [приведёт](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3) к неопределённому поведению.

Comment: по п.5 мы не то чтобы потеряем очистку, мы получим UB.

Comment: @alexolut, разве? В соседнем ответе про UB тоже ничего не говорится, кстати.

Comment: [да](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3) *...and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined*

Comment: @alexolut, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо. Не знал об UB.

Comment: @Qwertiy UB он настолько коварен, что комментарий о нём может появится в одном ответе и не появиться в другом :)